# The maximum pen area

Tags: graphing-functions, area

A farmer plans to construct a rectangular pen for his sheep. He has 60 m fence to cover
three sides with the remaining side being a brick wall. Advise him in using his amount of
fence in a way which maximizes the space for his sheep. How should the farmer choose
length l and width x from the wall, for this pen to achieve maximum area?

1. Retrieve the (quadratic) function f(x) which describes the area corresponding to x
   in a mathematical way. Graph this function f(x)
   for x running from 0 to 30.
2. Find the required width xmax which yields the largest area, and its corresponding
   length l as well.
3. Calculate this largest possible area up to 1 m2 precise.

Comment: Can you compute the length given $x$?  Does that tell you the area given $x$?  The question gives you an approach.  Follow it.

Comment: $l+2x=60$  work from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x+2l=60$$
$$l=(60-x)/2$$

$$A=lx$$
$$A=x(60-x)/2$$

Graph this on $(0,30)$ and find the max

Comment: From this I got that Xv=30 and Yv=450 and becouse x^2 is negative Xmax turns out to be 30. Then l would be 15 and the area=450. Could this be the answers?

Comment: That is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.